# I want to display data from a xml into a grid

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

I want to display data from a xml into a grid

The values ​​I need I get this foreach:

```
foreach (XElement wid in document.Root.Elements("widget"))
    {
                MessageBox.Show(wid.Attribute("caption").Value); //variable: nombreWidget 

        foreach (XElement service in wid.Elements("service"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(service.Attribute("caption").Value); //variable: nombreServicio 
                    MessageBox.Show(service.Element("xvalue").Value); //variable: valor 
                }
     }
```

Manually introduce values ​​to variables that I fill in:

```
public class Widgets
{
    public Widgets()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>
            {
                new WidgetCollectionItem
                    {
                        nombreWidget = "Widget", nombreServicio = "Servicio", valor = "valor"
                    },
        new WidgetCollectionItem
                    {
                        nombreWidget = "Widget2", nombreServicio = "Servicio2", valor = "valor2"
                    },
            };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem> Items { get; set; }
}


public class WidgetCollectionItem
{
    public string nombreWidget { get; set; }
    public string nombreServicio { get; set; }
    public string valor { get; set; }
}
```

But what I want to achieve is to enter the data foreach in  ObservableCollection

I try to mix the two, entering the foreach after ObservableCollection ,to tour and enter data, but does not work.

What is the solution?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking here.

Comment: I need to enter into a ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>, the data you get in the foreach